# Tidyr: Paired t-test using a Bonferroni Correction using the pairwise_t_test() Function: Incorrect P-Value and Adjusted P-Value Outputs in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, t-test, bonferroni

**Issue:**

During my analysis, I am having `problems conducting a pairwise t-test` (probably because I am a newbie to coding these types of statistical tests). I have nine parameters that are measurements of whistle types from dolphin species. I want to perform `multiple pairwise t-tests` between the levels of `within-subject independent variables`: `Species and Country`.

For the analysis, I am using the function `pairwise_t_test()` in the `tidyr` package using a `p.adjust.method = "bonferroni"`.

**Aim**

**(1) To configure if there are statistical differences between acoustic parameters and grouped by Species**

**(2) To configure if there are statistical differences between acoustic parameters that is grouped by Country.**

**(3) To configure if there are statistical differences between the acoustic parameters themselves**

Whenever I run the code(no matter what combination of `x = response vector` and `g=grouping vector or factor)` all the `p-values` and `p.adj` values are `equal to 1`, which cannot be possible as an `ANOVA` clearly shows `significant differences` between the acoustic parameters when they are grouped by either `Species` or `Country`. I have clearly made mistakes with my code, although, I cannot figure out what.

I'm really not sure what I am doing wrong. Would anyone be able to lend a hand?

I cannot share the real data but I have incorporated dummy data below, which shares similarities with the standardised format of the authentic data.

Many thanks in advance if anyone can provide any clarity.

**R-Code**

```
#Load required R packages
#install.packages("tidyverse")
#intall.packages("rstatix")
#intall.packages("ggpubr")
library(tidyverse)
library(rstatix)
library(ggpubr)

# Gather the acoustic parameter columns from the dataframe object Linear_Model into long format
# Convert ID, Species, and Country into factor variables
Gather_Parameters <- Linear_Model %>%
                     gather(key = "Acoustic_Parameters", value= "Acoustic_Values", 4:12)  %>%
                     convert_as_factor(ID, Species, Country)

#Check that the column headings have been labelled correctly
head(Gather_Parameters)

#Check the structure of the gathered object Gather_Parameters
str(Gather_Parameters)

#Make sure the column Acoustic_Parameters is a factor not a character
Gather_Parameters$Acoustic_Parameters<-as.factor(Gather_Parameters$Acoustic_Parameters)

#Run pairwise t-tests with a Bonferroni correction (Differences in acoustic parameters)
stat.test.Acoustic.Parameters <- Gather_Parameters  %>%
                                 pairwise_t_test(
                                 Acoustic_Values ~ Acoustic_Parameters, paired = TRUE,
                                 p.adjust.method = "bonferroni", conf.level = 0.95
                                 )
stat.test.Acoustic.Parameters

#Run pairwise t-tests with a Bonferroni correction (Differences in acoustic parameters between species)
stat.test.Species <- Gather_Parameters  %>%
                                    pairwise_t_test(
                                    Acoustic_Values ~ Species, paired = TRUE,
                                    p.adjust.method = "bonferroni", conf.level = 0.95
                                    )
stat.test.Species
```

**Outputs**

```
#Differences between Acoustic Parameters

# A tibble: 36 × 10
   .y.             group1      group2        n1    n2 statistic    df     p p.adj p.adj.signif
 * <chr>           <chr>       <chr>      <int> <int>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
 1 Acoustic_Values Center.Freq Delta.Freq   367   367  1.02e-13   366     1     1 ns          
 2 Acoustic_Values Center.Freq Delta.Time   367   367  2.96e-14   366     1     1 ns          
 3 Acoustic_Values Center.Freq End.Freq     367   367  2.42e-14   366     1     1 ns          
 4 Acoustic_Values Center.Freq High.Freq    367   367  3.05e-14   366     1     1 ns                  
# … with 32 more rows

#Differences between acoustic parameters between species 

Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not all arguments have the same length
> stat.test.Species
Error: object 'stat.test.Species' not found
```

**Dummy Data**

```
    structure(list(ID = 1:100, Low.Freq = c(-0.305241393634978, 0.367622254289095, 
-0.305244496865129, -0.305225284009329, -0.305183933825073, -0.30503844667324, 
4.37645428247052, 3.04558740482875, -0.302795590656283, -0.288881228628165, 
-0.305216510591365, -0.305241565242175, 1.61006981771271, -0.281558291899054, 
-0.305206013951129, -0.24096729073395, -0.30523096134744, -0.301419229430726, 
-0.236995885470424, -0.280664533014178, -0.301845351552587, -0.251254277027382, 
-0.304895969797659, -0.288671217170136, -0.268590658177386, -0.305227021532202, 
-0.30524444681303, -0.301258569342529, 2.91424767904839, -0.155040678311463, 
-0.30524443966273, -0.253519041563197, -0.305244082147736, -0.30524443966273, 
-0.305240178083997, -0.305178728406754, -0.305222895809166, -0.0891756265349218, 
-0.304912565643701, -0.305244232304034, -0.305243874789039, 2.52910751529936, 
-0.0983554675439024, -0.30518928224939, 0.378953713488455, -0.300386919184909, 
-0.300122372389631, -0.304699014787228, 2.07456666238668, -0.30524446111363, 
-0.304594005483064, 0.28897099334996, -0.305176368807791, -0.30360642036305, 
-0.304938399677198, -0.30524446826393, -0.175285644149552, -0.294921251400963, 
-0.305202810616779, -0.245870837692154, -0.305243889089639, -0.305238941082116, 
-0.305073275783997, -0.30524444681303, -0.234958915188459, -0.290401639795277, 
-0.252086829345211, 0.282331296376405, -0.30524448971483, 0.367148754280172, 
-0.236325244543272, -0.30524446826393, -0.30524448256453, -0.304772784431179, 
-0.305244504015429, 6.39300869212907, -0.270314745636825, -0.305239177042012, 
-0.30524444681303, -0.304840826684918, -0.30434971548737, 0.217041922394195, 
-0.301551545730165, -0.30524445396333, -0.273491888438426, -0.305240128031897, 
-0.305216145926071, -0.30524444681303, -0.30517832798996, -0.304642970736701, 
-0.304556516460748, -0.305203818809063, -0.305244103598636, -0.305219041797526, 
-0.304681503702801, -0.292349917757423, -0.299457272944893, -0.305193515226924, 
-0.305244504015429, -0.0513913897874896), High.Freq = c(-0.266644405143301, 
-0.266669883678681, -0.266698416788557, -0.201634323592084, -0.205081076956687, 
-0.260763877247484, -0.266697775595076, 4.39869797037446, -0.224835811718779, 
-0.229528573219555, -0.266698203057397, -0.266691247889228, -0.263661581978134, 
-0.266691523958643, -0.266299959567838, -0.266697659824031, 1.52882768024918, 
-0.266697811216936, -0.266698461315882, -0.26611585688979, -0.266693171469669, 
0.526717779885021, -0.25826926948482, -0.204886358964353, -0.260862273730324, 
-0.266698434599487, -0.266698416788557, -0.266692966643974, -0.248827900312221, 
-0.266690553262957, -0.26668602038127, -0.266442268898618, 0.539421033874184, 
-0.266689707243782, -0.266698470221347, 2.37118508881187, 4.07105015907316, 
-0.266698425694022, -0.266690508735632, -0.266693759230359, -0.266698425694022, 
-0.265815885206562, -0.266698452410417, -0.258451858233818, -0.266617626410031, 
-0.266698461315882, -0.266698283206582, 0.522334786078979, -0.261570970635422, 
-0.266698042759026, -0.26662338824589, -0.266696742561136, 0.288334600593007, 
-0.266698425694022, -0.266697748878681, 0.0951726690646137, 6.91913477861463, 
-0.205979469171856, -0.266667292188364, -0.265881126643188, 0.0548425965620802, 
-0.214740897185858, 0.253281274364417, -0.266698167435537, -0.26666926029613, 
-0.208745212722062, -0.266698301017512, -0.266694890224415, -0.266693269429784, 
-0.266697793406006, -0.23037589259292, -0.266696698033811, -0.266637191716647, 
-0.265876932169171, -0.265970760148464, -0.266698114002747, -0.26669555813429, 
-0.266184054940798, 0.603088482993923, -0.242863144528387, -0.266697793406006, 
-0.266656667968613, -0.259421636656467, -0.266698016042631, -0.265659095589684, 
-0.266692539181653, -0.266698443504952, -0.266316951195068, -0.266611873479638, 
-0.266698283206582, -0.266698434599487, -0.26669527315941, -0.266675280390474, 
-0.266698274301117, -0.266426942593344, -0.266648243398719, -0.266698167435537, 
0.195705555148554, -0.266381934373209, -0.266167312666589), Peak.Freq = c(0.0636364419783993, 
-0.365668088262647, 4.54355457872207, -0.154773439309682, -0.365550947507081, 
-0.0561218355651575, -0.365699571876284, -0.365712885793148, 
-0.0330877329653772, 4.5652869918095, -0.365697963152453, 0.0552959737955557, 
3.10359185795173, -0.364078303946581, -0.324243415055659, -0.346299438239501, 
-0.116119240212237, 1.46068529981252, -0.365696157039194, -0.365650545277306, 
-0.365712806837377, -0.365710872420991, -0.365674972218921, -0.365711948193369, 
-0.0272446062069381, -0.365370202943338, -0.365712634121629, 
-0.363244170770422, -0.365709530172886, -0.365712999292069, 0.140882381223789, 
-0.0652027855104291, -0.343599318656544, 0.0987686215264775, 
-0.0688165121876683, -0.365710798399956, -0.36571014208011, -0.365712964748919, 
-0.365712155452268, -0.318939008456645, -0.365712905532091, -0.365712742685813, 
-0.350552869507116, -0.365702345197736, -0.230985378714411, -0.365712964748919, 
-0.365691967448602, -0.365710497381079, -0.362197454115914, -0.365462926626761, 
2.21235913158754, -0.365156148913756, -0.364758700367372, -0.363451567841572, 
0.0960731702034729, -0.256689242403247, -0.36571297461839, -0.365712959814183, 
-0.357371026014843, -0.365713004226805, -0.365712984487862, -0.362491376842473, 
-0.365492090914628, -0.365607361405372, -0.365686435609905, -0.365711504067158, 
-0.365709446282379, -0.362499765893129, -0.365701032558045, -0.365710112471696, 
2.09321335343655, -0.365708340901587, -0.36571297461839, -0.36570897748249, 
-0.365484984895249, -0.365519883345977, -0.333039981118441, -0.365382845736149, 
-0.232943521310029, -0.365692781679989, -0.365713004226805, -0.365712935140505, 
-0.365712569970065, -0.365710388816894, 0.116948587484344, -0.365712560100593, 
-0.36571297461839, 0.921230748088983, -0.365712959814183, 3.7459370056508, 
0.125131933683144, -0.365712979553126, -0.323986655823505, -0.365446084373886, 
-0.365712994357333, -0.365711479393479, 1.11056818681009, -0.365688567415718, 
-0.363468568005988, 3.23568252849786), Delta.Freq = c(-0.274926096212803, 
-0.274925496340785, -0.274198459673172, -0.27491961266456, -0.274926096212803, 
-0.243214092103075, -0.274919711273659, -0.274925841472631, -0.20296778275922, 
1.7232996345582, -0.268206017612214, -0.20267538212917, -0.27486507361553, 
4.87675620104167, -0.274850487686341, -0.27413899838663, -0.274861088164456, 
-0.208007923883911, -0.274926087995378, -0.274926104430228, -0.274873849825318, 
-0.273437756215763, -0.272792745883456, -0.274870661464459, -0.274925866124906, 
-0.274614203850901, -0.274926137299927, -0.274926120865077, 4.65209578985487, 
-0.270278485040511, -0.274925981168854, -0.274925742863532, 1.93926248493048, 
0.305853358925121, -0.210579049307131, -0.274926104430228, 0.435752209400366, 
-0.274925964734004, 0.47203609289455, -0.274926120865077, -0.274331557304202, 
-0.270207034531046, -0.267780724786757, -0.274322830398963, -0.221774485419356, 
-0.274907574137089, -0.226126918471983, -0.274668693595382, -0.274915873736233, 
-0.274923228331514, -0.274853684264625, -0.274926112647652, -0.274905034952796, 
-0.274245660561771, -0.0297488376360538, -0.274883160167725, 
-0.274925833255206, 0.00242850281064593, -0.274274437983755, 
-0.274911871850309, -0.204896617817773, -0.274925808602931, -0.256115342362193, 
-0.274919053879667, -0.268340298552428, -0.274860184247717, -0.274926096212803, 
-0.274926014038554, -0.23882065410022, -0.271590569490971, -0.27434189482472, 
-0.267117217031009, -0.274857776542223, -0.263446616591646, -0.274919300402414, 
-0.274925562080184, -0.27491178967606, -0.274417421176933, -0.203356088955223, 
2.19646881272281, -0.274549269759378, 0.476286892836072, -0.274269630790191, 
-0.274533631999802, -0.274881130463775, -0.274925989386279, -0.274891739159315, 
-0.274902635464727, 5.92132935241066, -0.274923055765591, 0.167247111377754, 
-0.274925545645335, -0.274925019730141, -0.274921954630655, -0.273017024061123, 
-0.167046928662061, -0.274912233417004, -0.2748556235769, -0.274925948299155, 
-0.274926079777953), Delta.Time = c(-0.278154257708137, -0.28502622401883, 
-0.28506394183835, -0.285041063317152, -0.267319599485717, -0.285065394281649, 
0.0427549484391774, -0.285066120503298, -0.285062428453374, -0.285066450604048, 
-0.28469783979293, -0.284624770722344, -0.285040255839933, -0.281841239316685, 
-0.285066460760994, -0.285066013855364, 4.38614483332002, -0.284652869913862, 
-0.269143294401949, -0.262665473464988, -0.285036970067855, -0.285066435368629, 
-0.0483907489929674, -0.285064332880776, -0.27956331053331, -0.285066232229706, 
-0.205335007369294, -0.285066440447102, 0.172847430482172, 1.98226799805125, 
-0.27322311621665, -0.281198406194999, -0.0351119435634658, -0.285064541098173, 
-0.285066242386652, -0.282561788311819, -0.285066242386652, 3.7705876725097, 
-0.054796958381114, -0.25324556611453, -0.285066445525575, -0.267566976987616, 
-0.285064693452365, -0.276122132100008, -0.285065389203176, -0.285061605740736, 
4.3312471995934, -0.285066445525575, -0.285046898482714, -0.238869617519104, 
-0.28429117598307, -0.244590781517375, -0.12069191382271, -0.285066318563748, 
-0.258650199043055, -0.285065897050483, -0.24542182792965, -0.285066120503298, 
-0.285065262241349, -0.285040753530295, -0.285066465839467, -0.285066470917941, 
-0.211566593460797, 0.334721799419951, -0.285066435368629, -0.28254956442713, 
-0.285066328720695, -0.239535537379383, -0.285051875386326, -0.285061605740736, 
-0.285066277935964, -0.285066430290156, -0.285062971849993, 4.45633140321739, 
-0.284633312714054, -0.282120489315595, -0.284579277760549, -0.280079120886473, 
0.0462737056271547, -0.284368145320977, -0.285066328720695, -0.285027772953118, 
-0.285028250329587, -0.285066110346352, -0.285066465839467, -0.285064876277395, 
-0.285066445525575, -0.285054221640887, -0.241263883963654, -0.0245504107014295, 
-0.285062154215828, -0.280544298863089, -0.284250182548418, -0.285066445525575, 
4.03591543868794, -0.285066465839467, -0.285066440447102, 0.105819091890797, 
-0.284098844050818, -0.285026584590419), Peak.Time = c(-0.332777588178629, 
-0.338109799295758, 2.5304495505853, -0.297166994152313, -0.313944662904678, 
-0.336805487504723, -0.340495210463669, -0.340476048926995, -0.340389132028096, 
0.03721633680403, -0.340491602532767, -0.340490354241345, 3.71813598121804, 
-0.340126727476943, 3.54373807157349, -0.339850512714367, 0.710292516801162, 
-0.34046304457459, -0.340490438514184, 0.22875866006038, -0.340454043182019, 
-0.340495194662512, -0.340495184128407, -0.340494852304105, -0.340491418185932, 
-0.33635345326559, -0.340034422383428, -0.340486983327802, -0.340490601792809, 
-0.0897859701111449, 0.0771595080702495, -0.340494936576943, 
-0.340456355418027, -0.340492102902746, -0.305690875752333, -0.34049019096272, 
-0.340462059635789, 0.0572427919556391, -0.310251537429875, -0.205409668820293, 
-0.340492850824188, 1.39008009612354, -0.340495194662512, -0.340495205196616, 
-0.340480978888052, -0.227951246839558, -0.00641112182304615, 
-0.340491486657614, -0.340491096895735, -0.33570314610547, -0.340492698079668, 
-0.340494952378101, -0.340490359508398, -0.337440946844095, -0.340453869369289, 
-0.340492403124733, -0.329131592288806, -0.34049471009369, -0.340495184128407, 
-0.340491444521195, -0.340495189395459, 3.10041922406621, 2.01837652336927, 
-0.340495205196616, -0.172095630787703, -0.340491818481916, -0.340495178861354, 
-0.337282793061328, -0.319138924652091, -0.338095383373307, -0.314581876172503, 
-0.34049516832725, -0.340112232548706, -0.340442561007761, 0.102415250867809, 
-0.340022539913187, -0.340495189395459, -0.340468732991195, -0.34047348387247, 
-0.340373594223482, -0.340494789099476, 0.921674994298265, -0.340476380751297, 
4.39246641494009, -0.340459283899168, -0.340475211465662, -0.339431276410602, 
-0.340391855094193, -0.23287393936462, -0.240715685006795, 4.56165704795072, 
-0.332635182882573, -0.338914457426804, -0.339738693191665, -0.313355448285482, 
-0.338297043008995, -0.340490933617111, -0.340201356342565, -0.340494804900633, 
-0.26568318309407), Center_Freq = c(-0.363953202262907, -0.319648715586073, 
1.17656599161085, -0.364035405672014, 0.104087126261498, -0.363861059644472, 
-0.364025656024926, -0.364242310295061, -0.364270278410381, -0.364248924480237, 
-0.364255717981046, 3.49889839087943, -0.364268449390933, -0.0885893751797284, 
-0.364270001751977, -0.364269673860536, -0.340186831329626, -0.342886571624991, 
-0.364270216930736, -0.364266215630486, -0.362523252315533, -0.364266374452903, 
-0.364041107909118, -0.364269904409206, 0.668693759127556, -0.36426999150537, 
-0.364270365506546, -0.36393519385013, -0.364267322264102, 0.0921810857367065, 
-0.359421061138548, -0.328709934099133, -0.364020640310528, -0.352395346586126, 
-0.338007306176504, -0.364257844152114, -0.364270329643419, -0.361414384939187, 
1.94254706633025, -0.256646936706091, -0.364270324520115, -0.327208252775573, 
-0.364270068354926, -0.364270324520115, 2.97380567387671, -0.364036983649578, 
-0.364073159297549, 0.102233171693513, -0.364270175944306, -0.358550335168379, 
-0.352509919028498, -0.364254995595214, -0.364270324520115, -0.364253617426497, 
-0.364269648244017, -0.363995536122019, -0.360848090802769, -0.361372640260009, 
-0.364269940272332, -0.364265395901882, 2.4817161526806, -0.363960764259283, 
-0.36423657219483, 4.02611351332146, 2.74975326086784, -0.364247797353406, 
-0.364269965888851, -0.339242642306593, -0.364266553768535, -0.364270329643419, 
-0.363981129391797, -0.363629240395156, 0.00995617412378297, 
-0.361624307188158, -0.364270334766723, -0.341519115737093, 3.49889839087943, 
-0.364268449390933, -0.0885893751797284, -0.364270001751977, 
-0.364269673860536, -0.364267762868227, -0.363080099079785, -0.297011105817705, 
-0.364261701999858, -0.364226407560136, -0.364270252793862, -0.334174992978214, 
-0.364247059597663, 2.93855996189703, -0.345250766262766, -0.364239999685057, 
-0.364225116487584, -0.364270334766723, -0.353070710736658, -0.0485353964953112, 
-0.364079286768867, 3.30620785158585, -0.364160798531964, -0.364133890940525
), Start.Freq = c(-0.314883756292511, -0.204080449334261, -0.31358353421603, 
-0.316852288595455, -0.317065821301137, -0.282449793143377, -0.313999180027078, 
-0.317065544896647, 1.00072737562172, -0.31481998363436, -0.315310186997268, 
-0.317042030040595, -0.31211238155553, -0.317056182974201, -0.317066005570797, 
0.140033911801816, -0.317064224297417, -0.317065637031477, -0.317061214559638, 
-0.279507170469072, 0.0458002913438, -0.317044911813333, -0.26384323077076, 
4.49442142321656, -0.317066061875415, -0.31686966624811, 4.17977297846084, 
-0.317033917056955, -0.313286696268242, -0.317065939028975, -0.317065857131348, 
-0.317066072112618, -0.317066066994017, -0.316667624803167, -0.304952885915291, 
-0.317065867368552, -0.298302112738786, -0.27994466759063, -0.317066066994017, 
-0.317065785470925, -0.317049477606019, -0.314771182886081, -0.317066092587025, 
-0.313456807875995, -0.317065360626987, -0.279067456992993, -0.317066087468423, 
-0.317063553760599, 4.00778192254842, -0.316661840783285, -0.317061419303704, 
-0.317065427168808, -0.28077744872581, -0.317061352761883, -0.267950140817113, 
-0.302864726772822, -0.317057646894277, 0.0591986253357035, -0.317066061875415, 
-0.317065918554568, -0.317066005570797, -0.317065606319867, -0.317066092587025, 
0.156637514156687, -0.177047020430414, -0.317027421551442, -0.316733291343934, 
-0.317027810565168, -0.316698402954982, -0.317023874360488, -0.316734453266512, 
-0.316699928298278, 1.47132042860769, 1.11739378485778, -0.31706567798029, 
-0.317066066994017, -0.31706589296156, -0.315254767897035, -0.317066097705627, 
-0.317065570489655, -0.317059673860536, -0.317041774110512, -0.317065949266178, 
-0.3170657086919, -0.316650544029409, -0.317066026045203, -0.317066051638212, 
2.0926468261124, 3.87179923634441, -0.020457417204293, -0.317065872487153, 
-0.317065974859187, -0.316854725049848, -0.31706607723122, -0.31572784441877, 
-0.266231196649984, 3.6424622081951, -0.312302128119272, 0.0156809956980382, 
-0.315319758782383), End.Freq = c(0.0901630463153326, -0.283190637256532, 
0.0925278628935432, -0.343988770817179, -0.301125664847612, -0.356201777043296, 
-0.356199413226311, -0.356199922452842, -0.356202223402354, -0.356202242262596, 
-0.341950645062494, -0.352443848696794, -0.355224759931907, -0.356183287719482, 
-0.356202248549344, -0.356198790838328, -0.356202248549344, -0.356098718394781, 
-0.343970470095784, 3.84448345997439, -0.35211727103472, -0.215414559962246, 
0.228846214809494, -0.355120035295357, -0.356073571405575, -0.208093755891021, 
-0.355004566607669, -0.213121915243057, -0.356201997079452, -0.355709078370525, 
0.936486131100715, -0.356200903185421, 0.0833441132811919, -0.356052121023782, 
-0.356201858771011, -0.354239878099643, -0.307727906275763, -0.356202248549344, 
-0.356199620688972, -0.351521337684509, 3.73991255325663, -0.355915887209757, 
-0.355960277932454, 0.216238872358885, -0.356202034799935, -0.349183283789562, 
-0.341771158427034, -0.356183407167681, -0.356202217115607, -0.356181716032657, 
-0.356201387264963, -0.355852761980102, -0.35596054197584, -0.30175359145484, 
-0.356202185681871, -0.356201670168592, -0.356200104768514, -0.356202235975849, 
-0.356201997079452, -0.304425729388141, -0.350478083403551, -0.347247896059279, 
0.191389548063847, -0.355865027424088, -0.352002833373589, -0.35264650199606, 
-0.35620174560956, -0.356196169264703, 3.13607514599423, -0.355822359270152, 
-0.356160800024384, 5.0311874332169, 3.46498040710299, -0.356174574287722, 
-0.356201777043296, -0.356202229689102, -0.174020220477998, -0.308817204693958, 
-0.356202235975849, -0.356198294185291, 1.81813256294942, -0.356197231724997, 
-0.349694666675313, -0.356198489074457, -0.356185048008727, -0.356151571079346, 
0.0296214937723049, 2.34680839821657, -0.350031787212612, -0.356151319609454, 
1.805101336562, -0.355920740578674, -0.355798765107529, -0.274591750032393, 
0.419381029095111, -0.351054842174491, 0.421755131199086, -0.196860551805348, 
-0.356202254836091, -0.351167286936727), Species = c("Truncatus_Tursiops", 
"Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", 
"Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", 
"Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", 
"Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", 
"Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", 
"Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", 
"Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", 
"Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", 
"Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", 
"Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", 
"Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", 
"Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", 
"Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", 
"Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", 
"Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", 
"Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", 
"Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", 
"Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", 
"Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", 
"Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", 
"Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", 
"Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", 
"Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", 
"Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", 
"Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", 
"Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", "Grampus_griseus", 
"Grampus_griseus", "Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", 
"Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", 
"Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", "Truncatus_Tursiops", 
"Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus", 
"Delphinus_Delphinus", "Delphinus_Delphinus"), Country = c("Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", "Holland", 
"Holland", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "France")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```